# Yacc union on struct type

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

I have this problem where my YACC file doesn't seem to be able to access types defined in my header file.

If I replace my header file with `%code requires{  }` it does recognize it but that is not really what I want.

My st.h header file:

```
struct node {
    int item;
    int identifier;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *middle;
    struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node NODE;
typedef NODE *TREE;
```

My parser.y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "st.h"
%}

%union {
    int value;
    TREE token;
}
```

Yacc (or C) gives me this error:

> error: unknown type name ‘TREE’

I understand that this is most likely a mistake on my end and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Note: **never ever** `typedef` a pointer! And read [ask], provide **all** required information. It should be no problem to specify the **exact** error message, which it originates from and where it arises.

Comment: Is it yacc or C which gives the error? (Hint: which command was running when the error was produced?) And if it's C, does the error pertain to the file which yacc/bison generated or the file which (f)lex generated? (Hint: the error message will have a filename beside it.)

Comment: Also: [mcve]. The code as presented compiles correctly.

Comment: Well, which is it? Yacc? Or C?

Comment: The error says it's the `TREE token;` line in my yacc file. I wasn't sure if that counted as C or Yacc. @EJP @rici

Comment: @diederik: does your file really look like the one in the question? Order matters.

Comment: You stated 'YACC (or C) gives me this error'. I am asking you which it is. Not what file the code is in. An error message is produced by a program, and that program is either *yacc(1)* or the C compiler. Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

You're (likely) getting this error when trying to compile some other source file (NOT your parser file) that has an `#include "y.tab.h"` in it.  The problem being that since your `%union` uses types defined in `st.h`, you need to always `#include "st.h"` BEFORE `#include "y.tab.h"` in every file that wants to include the latter.

Comment: I solved mine by including the header in Lex file too, since global variable yyval need to known the declarations of these types first.